# ошибка при создании string

Tags: c++, mingw

Попытка запустить любую програму в которой имеется обьект string приводит к ошибке:

> The procedure entry point
>   _ZNSt7_cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEEC1EPKcRKS3_ could not be located in the dynamic library 
>   *путь к проекту*

Даже вот такая банальная програма выдает ошибку:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string test;
    return 0;
}
```

Прошу помочь в решении проблемы.

Comment: проверяйте настройки линковщика и библиотеки в системе... через какую IDE собираете?

Comment: У вас скорее всего несколько gcc установлено. Проверьте, к какому обращяетесь.

Comment: @0xdb, у меня действительно несколько gcc, спасибо!

Comment: @Evertum Подлечили?

Comment: @0xdb, удалил лишний, но проблема увы не прошла.

Comment: @Evertum Странно. Но причина по-моему очевидна - линкуетесь с одной библиотекой, запускаете с другой.  Посмотрите с ldd, пути соответствуют.

Answer (score 2):

В коде приведенной программы ошибок нет. Вам следует всего-лишь добавить в системную переменную PATH путь к папке "mingw32\bin". Или в папке проекта создать  пакетный файл. Например "D:\tests\env.cmd"

```
PUSHD
SETLOCAL
SET "_MINGW=D:\MinGW\i686-6.2.0-release-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0\mingw32\"
SET "PATH=%_MINGW%bin;%_MINGW%opt\bin;%PATH%"
cmd.exe /K
ENDLOCAL
POPD
```

Только изменить путь на тот, где у Вас лежит Mingw. Запустите пакетный файл, и в получившемся окне наберите команду для компиляции. Например, ваш файл с кодом "D:\tests\test.cpp". Тогда:

```
D:\tests>c++ test.cpp -o test

D:\tests>test.exe
```

Если будут ошибки, значит Вам надо просто скачать свежий мингвей. Например: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/5.3.0/threads-posix/sjlj/i686-5.3.0-release-posix-sjlj-rt_v4-rev0.7z

В случае использования какой-нибудь среды разработчика, думаю это как раз Ваш случай, надо внимательно проверить все настройки окружения в опциях IDE.